# drawString on large JPanel turns messy on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: java, swing, graphics, java-2d

I've experienced a problem on the `Graphics drawString` method. Briefly, I observe unexpected behaviour of `drawString` on Linux where the string goes messy if the panel size is large.

As an example. I have modified the ScrollDemo2 class from Oracle to draw strings on the `drawingPane`:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class ScrollDemo2 extends JPanel
                          {
    private Dimension area; 
    private JPanel drawingPane;

    public ScrollDemo2() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        area = new Dimension(100000,1000);

        drawingPane = new DrawingPane();
        drawingPane.setBackground(Color.white);
        drawingPane.setPreferredSize(area);
        drawingPane.revalidate();
        drawingPane.repaint();

        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(drawingPane);
        scroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));

        add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public class DrawingPane extends JPanel {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            // drawString gives correct results in Windows but gives messy strings in Linux; drawLine gives correct lines in both Windows and Linux
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i += 100)
                g.drawString("Mark " + i, i, 20);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i += 100)
                g.drawLine(i, i % 1000 / 10 + 25, i, i % 1000 / 10 + 35);

        }

    }


    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ScrollDemo2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JComponent newContentPane = new ScrollDemo2();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Program runs on Windows 7

[image]

The program displays correct strings on Windows 7.

Program runs on Linux 14.04

[image]

The program displays messy strings on Linux.

A `drawLine` method is added in addition to the `drawString` method, and the `drawLine` method works properly in both Windows and Linux.

Why is it? How should I rewrite the code to solve the problem on Linux?

Comment: Don't know why the problem is occurring, but if this were my program, I'd draw a static (unchanging) image onto a BufferedImage, and then would display that image in my JPanel's paintComponent method or as an ImageIcon in a JLabel.

Comment: Try to `g.setColor(Color.white); g.fillRect(0,0, this.width, this.height);` before drawing strings

Comment: @Oneiros The panel will become white in both Windows and Linux. (No correct string and no messy string will display)

Comment: You have to setColor(Color.black) back again before drawing strings

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Thanks for the suggestions. I didn't use a BufferedImage before and I should look it up now. Will it improve the performance?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: @Oneiros Oh thanks for pointing that out. But it can't solve the problem and the messy string still appears in Linux

Comment: Is there some size limitation on Linux? Try using some other (smaller) value instead of 100000, to see if you have the same problem.

Comment: @ camickr Yes, only a panel with large size has such problem. drawString works well when I set the width to, e.g., 10000. However, drawLine method does not have a similar problem even I set it to 100000. So I suppose it's not a linux limitation?

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments, if drawing a static (stable unchanging background image) use a BufferedImage. For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class ScrollDemo2B extends JPanel
                          {
    private static final int IMG_W = 100000;
    private static final int IMG_H = 1000;
    // private Dimension area; 
    private JPanel drawingPane;
    private BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(IMG_W, IMG_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    public ScrollDemo2B() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i += 100) {
            g2.drawString("Mark " + i, i, 20);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i += 100) {
            g2.drawLine(i, i % 1000 / 10 + 25, i, i % 1000 / 10 + 35);
        }
        g2.dispose();

        drawingPane = new DrawingPane();
        drawingPane.setBackground(Color.white);
        drawingPane.revalidate();
        drawingPane.repaint();

        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(drawingPane);
        scroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));

        add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public class DrawingPane extends JPanel {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (img != null) {
                g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            if (isPreferredSizeSet() || img == null) {
                return super.getPreferredSize();
            }
            int w = img.getWidth();
            int h = img.getHeight();
            return new Dimension(w, h);
        }

    }


    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ScrollDemo2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JComponent newContentPane = new ScrollDemo2B();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then if you have mobile sprites or dynamic images, you would draw them within the paintComponent method.

Comment: It works in Windows with correct strings and lines but it does not work on Linux with only a blank white panel displayed (No strings and lines). Thanks though for teaching me another strategy :)